# Button to Trigger Nav-Tab with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, button, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, nav

This button triggers the next tab to load content, but the tab itself does not switch, it remains on the first tab..

```
<br><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Review</a><br>
```

Here is the code for nav nav-tabs:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Shipping</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Quantities</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Summary</a></li>
  </ul>
```

ANY SOLUTION *for switching both the tab&content* IS APPRECIATED

..perhaps a way to change the button to trigger the `next()` function in  * bootstrap-tab.js v2.3.1:

```
  , activate: function ( element, container, callback) {
      var $active = container.find('> .active')
        , transition = callback
            && $.support.transition
            && $active.hasClass('fade')

      function next() {
        $active
          .removeClass('active')
          .find('> .dropdown-menu > .active')
          .removeClass('active')

        element.addClass('active')

        if (transition) {
          element[0].offsetWidth // reflow for transition
          element.addClass('in')
        } else {
          element.removeClass('fade')
        }

        if ( element.parent('.dropdown-menu') ) {
          element.closest('li.dropdown').addClass('active')
        }

        callback && callback()
      }

      transition ?
        $active.one($.support.transition.end, next) :
        next()

      $active.removeClass('in')
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could assign your Review button a click handler using jQuery...

JS:

```
$('#btnReview').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" id="btnReview">Review</a>
```

[**Working Demo**](http://bootply.com/61038)

Comment: This is not an elegant markup-only solution. Definitely needs a fix in bootstrap.

Answer (score 10):

By changing 'data-toggle' to 'data-trigger' for the triggering link, the following code can trigger any tab with the same HREF attribute, for all triggers with similar markup.

(N.B. Selectors are not optimised, it's just a guide to a more flexible solution)

JS:

```
$( '[data-trigger="tab"]' ).click( function( e ) {
    var href = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
    e.preventDefault();
    $( '[data-toggle="tab"][href="' + href + '"]' ).trigger( 'click' );
} );
```

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#tab2" data-trigger="tab">Review</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Bootstrap 4

```
var nextTab;    
    $('.nav-link').map(function(element) {
                    if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                        nextTab = $(this).parent().next('li');
                    }
                })

    nextTab.find('a').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple with Bootstrap 4 & JQuery, 
i'm using this solution:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        activaTab('aaa');
    });

    function activaTab(tab){
        $('.tab-pane a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
    };
```

Comment: .tab('show'); did the magic. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You can with jquery;

JS:

```
function change_tab(tab_id){

   $(".nav-link").attr("class","nav-link");//clear classes
   $(".tab-pane").attr("class","tab-pane fade");//clear classes

   var tab_content = "#"+tab_id;
   var tab = "#"+tab_id+"-tab";
   $(tab).attr("class","nav-link active show");
   $(tab_content).attr("class"," tab-pane fade active show");
}
```

HTML :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="change_tab('tabid')">Review</a>
```