# How to make a nav tab active from outside with a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs piluku-tabs " role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Personal Detail</a>

    </li>
    <li role="presentation">

        <a href="#join" aria-controls="join" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Joining Detail</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">

        <a href="#education" aria-controls="education" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id ="id2">Education Detail</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">

        <a href="#experience" aria-controls="education" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Experience Detail</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<a href="#join" aria-controls="join" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary clickme">Next</button></a>
```

I am using a next button to move next tab. The tab is changing, but active stands only in first tab of the nav tab. How to change the active from first to selected tab?

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462774/button-to-trigger-nav-tab-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fire event on button click like this

```
$('.clickme').click(function(){
  $('.nav-tabs > .active').next('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```